# GWT - how do I send the form asynchronously?

Tags: java, web-applications, gwt

I am adding a file upload functionality to an application.
I'm following some tutorials, so far I get something like this:

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "fileupload");
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();

submit.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        String filename = fileUpload.getFilename();
        if (filename.length() == 0) {
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

I've made the fileupload servlet, and I guess it's okay. The problem is, after the form.submit() the page gets reloaded, but I would like to send it asynchronously instead.

Something like that is dead simple in php and jquery.

Could anybody help?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

For submitting arbitrary data (objects) use [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html). For file upload take a look at [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/).